# function prototype with void* parameter

Tags: c, void-pointers, function-prototypes

I have two functions, each taking a pointer to a different type:

```
void processA(A *);
void processB(B *);
```

Is there a function pointer type that would be able to hold a pointer to either function without casting?
I tried to use

```
typedef void(*processor_t)(void*);
processor_t Ps[] = {processA, processB};
```

but it didn't work (compiler complains about incompatible pointer initialization).

Edit: Another part of code would iterate through the entries of Ps, without knowing the types. This code would be passing a char* as a parameter. Like this:

```
Ps[i](data_pointers[j]);
```

Edit: Thanks everyone. In the end, I will probably use something like this:

```
void processA(void*);
void processB(void*);

typedef void(*processor_t)(void*);
processor_t Ps[] = {processA, processB};

...

void processA(void *arg)
{
  A *data = arg;
  ...
}
```

Comment: without a parameter list it will compile if this is pure C

Comment: If this were allowed then it would easily allow me to pass a `A*` to `processB`.  After all any pointer type is convertible to `void*` hence it would trivially allow for me to violate type safety.

Comment: Technically speaking it compiles, it just throws a warning. My question was rather whether it is possible to get rid of the warning without casting the initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without casts by using a union:

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;

void processA(A *);
void processB(B *);

typedef union { void (*A)(A *); void (*B)(B *); } U;

U Ps[] = { {.A = processA}, {.B = processB} };

int main(void)
{
    Ps[0].A(0); // 0 used for example; normally you would supply a pointer to an A.
    Ps[1].B(0); // 0 used for example; normally you would supply a pointer to a B.
    return 0;
}
```

You **must** call the function using the correct member name; this method only allows you to store one pointer or the other in each array element, not to perform weird function aliasing.

---

Another alternative is to use proxy functions that do have the type needed when calling with a parameter that is a pointer to `char` and that call the actual function with its proper type:

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;

void processA(A *);
void processB(B *);

typedef void (*processor_t)();

void processAproxy(char *A) { processA(A); }
void processBproxy(char *B) { processB(B); }

processor_t Ps[] = { processAproxy, processBproxy };

int main(void)
{
    char *a = (char *) address of some A object;
    char *b = (char *) address of some B object;
    Ps[0](a);
    Ps[1](b);
    return 0;
}
```

I used `char *` above since you stated you are using it, but I would generally prefer `void *`.

Comment: In my case, there's a code that iterates across the array Ps.

Comment: @cvoque: Saying there is code that iterates through the array does not convey any information about how the elements of the array are used. The code could contain a switch statement or other dispatching.

Comment: @cvoque: How are you going to call these functions? Presumably you have some pointer you want to pass them. What type is that pointer? E.g., are you calling each function, regardless of type, by passing it a `void *` that has been converted from an original `A *` or a `B *`? Or are you passing them actual `A *` and `B *` values?

Comment: I mean, In my case, there's a generic code that iterates through the entries of array Ps, without knowing what type exactly is each function. It is always passing a char*.

Comment: @cvoque: If you want to do this **correctly**, in a way defined by the C standard, you need another solution. As noted in my comment to [Andrey’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527037/298225), calling a function declared to take one pointer type with an argument that is another pointer type is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you well. Could you please cite a part of the C standard that implies that void* and A* are not compatible in this context and casting would result in an undefined behavior? I apologize if this is too elementary.

Comment: @cvoque: In C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.7, compatible types are defined. Mostly, they need to be the same. `void *` or `char *` are not compatible with `A *`. (They cannot be because some C implementations keep additional information for `char` pointers than for pointers to larger objects; different types of pointers might have different representations in the machine.) Then we have to consider whether calling a function using one type of expression when the function is declared with another typeof expression is allowed.…

Comment: This is covered in 6.5.2.2 6: “If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype [this includes the `processor_t` type; it does not include a prototype],… If a function is defined with a type that includes a prototype [your `processA` and `processB` do include a prototype], and either … or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the arguments, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: In other words, you can take a pointer to `processA` and convert it to a pointer to a function which does not include a prototype, but then you **must** call it with an argument that has type `A *`. If you call the converted pointer with an argument that has type `void *`, the behavior is not defined. I expect it is **very likely it will work** on most C implementations without different pointer representations (all of today’s normal platforms), but it is not proper C and it could fail, at least in theory. And the optimizer developers keep getting more clever and aggressive about optimizing.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally got it. I will make the processA and processB take char* and do the casting to A* and B* respectively inside of functions. Would you agree this is a correct solution?

Comment: @cvoque: I think that does result in behavior defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 4):

If you `typedef void (*processor_t)();` then this will compile in C.  This is because an empty argument list leaves the number and types of arguments to a function unspecified, so this typedef just defines a type which is "pointer to function returning void, taking an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type."

Edit: Incidentally, you don't need the ampersands in front of the function names in the initializer list.  In C, a function name in that context decays to a pointer to the function.

Comment: I wonder, would ellipsis achieve the same effect? (Making it compile without warning)

Comment: Just tried it, got `test1.c:4:29: error: ISO C requires a named argument before ‘...’`

Comment: Well, that answers that. I suppose I should have guessed :) Thanks.

Comment: The behavior of this might not be defined by the C standard. `processA` is a function taking a pointer to an `A`. The type that `processor_t` points to is a function without a parameter list. It is legal to convert a pointer to the first type of function to a pointer to the second type. However, if the second type is used to call a function and an argument of type `void *` is used, then the `void *` argument is a different type from the `A *` parameter that is required. They are not compatible, as the C standard defines it, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: This may happen to work in many C implementations, but I do not know that any C implementation guarantees it will work, and optimization may, at least in theory, break the code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but re: "The type that processor_t points to is a function without a parameter list," I believe that `processor_t` points to a function with an *unspecified* parameter list, and that `typedef void (*processor_t)(void);` is the way to specify a pointer-to-function with empty parameter list.

Comment: @Andrey: You are correct, I used the wrong terminology. However, the point is correct: If you call `processA`, which is a function that takes a pointer to an `A`, using a pointer to a function with an unspecified parameter list and with an argument that is a pointer to `void`, the behavior is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you cast them

```
processor_t Ps[] = {(processor_t)processA, (processor_t)processB};
```

By the way, if your code is ridden with this type of things and `switch`'s all over the place to figure out which function you need to call, you might want to take a look at object oriented programming. I personally don't like it much (especially C++...), but it does make a good job removing this kind of code with virtual inheritance.